# Android: Dynamic number of CheckBoxes for each Row in a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox, android-viewholder

My app shows a `ListView` with a `TextView` and checkbox for each row. The `TextView` contains different types of food.

Each row has one checkbox. I want to change that. Each type of food has an attribute called `numberOfPortions`. This number should determine the number of checkboxes in the row.

For example:

```
ListItem Beans numberOfPortions = 3
```

This means that the row in my `ListView` with beans should have 3 checkboxes instead of previously 1 checkbox.

How can I achieve that? If I add three checkboxes to my row layout, three checkboxes will be shown in each row, but there are also rows were `numberOfPortions` is 1 or 2 so that only one or two checkboxes should be shown.

This image shows how my list should look like:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I added this piece of code to my Adapter. It should add new CheckBoxes to each row dependent on the Integer numCheckBox:

```
int numCheckBox = item.numCheckBox;
CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[numCheckBox];
for(int i = 0; i < numCheckBox; i++){
    cb[i] = new CheckBox(parent.getContext());
     holder.rl.addView(cb[i]);
}
```

I am getting a `NullPointerException`. But, I don't understand why it keeps occurring?

```
Process: com.example.xx.myapplication, PID: 23887
java.lang.NullPointerException
      at com.example.timofocken.myapplication.ItemListAdapter.getView(ItemListAdapter.java:103)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2458)
      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1891)
      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:792)
```

Here is my Adapter:

```
public class ItemListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<Object> itemArray;
    int resIdImage;
    private static final int TYPE_ListElement = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_DIVIDER = 1;

    public ItemListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Object> itemArray, int resource) {
        this.itemArray = itemArray;
        this.resIdImage = resource;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return itemArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemArray.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        // TYPE_PERSON and TYPE_DIVIDER
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (getItem(position) instanceof ItemList) {
            return TYPE_ListElement;
        }

        return TYPE_DIVIDER;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return (getItemViewType(position) == TYPE_ListElement);
    }

    public class DataHolder{
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        CheckBox cb;
        RelativeLayout rl;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        DataHolder holder =  null;
        int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            switch (type) {
                case TYPE_ListElement:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(resIdImage, parent, false);
                    holder = new DataHolder();
                    holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
                    holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameLabel);
                    holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
                    holder.rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.row_layout);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                    break;
                case TYPE_DIVIDER:
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_header, parent, false);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            holder = (DataHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ListElement:
                ItemList item = (ItemList) getItem(position);
                holder.textView.setText(item.getTitle());
                holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.resIdImage);
                holder.cb.setChecked(item.checked);

                int numCheckBox = item.numCheckBox;
                CheckBox[] cb = new CheckBox[numCheckBox];
                for(int i = 0; i < numCheckBox; i++){
                    cb[i] = new CheckBox(parent.getContext());
                     holder.rl.addView(cb[i]);
                }

                break;
            case TYPE_DIVIDER:
                TextView title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.headerTitle);
                String titleString = (String)getItem(position);
                title.setText(titleString);
                break;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

My row layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:gravity="right|center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's OK to put all three checkboxes, just check the number of checkboxes you have to show on each row in your **getView** method (inside the adapter class as you know), then you can change the extra checkboxes visibility to GONE to not to show them. any question?

Comment: Okay thank you! I will try it later

Comment: I edited my question. Would be nice if you can check it out :)

Comment: Do you have any upper limit of the checkboxes? For example, a row can have at most 5 checkboxes or something like that?

Comment: yes the upper limit is 3

Comment: Oh, then it is simple. Just have three checkboxes in your layout and set the visibility based on the `numberOfPortions` value. Let me write an answer to clear up this thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure if this is the graceful solution to the problem specified in your question. However, after checking the desired UI and your comment later above, I think there is a workaround which involves less trouble.

I would like to suggest keeping three checkboxes (as three is the max limit of checkboxes a row can have) in your row layout. So the final layout of each row should look like the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:gravity="right|center" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:gravity="right|center" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:gravity="right|center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The `DataHolder` class inside your Adapter should look like this.

```
public class DataHolder{
    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textView;
    CheckBox cb1;
    CheckBox cb2;
    CheckBox cb3;
    RelativeLayout rl;
}
```

Then in your `getView` function take three different references.

```
holder.cb1 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
holder.cb2 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox2);
holder.cb3 = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox3);
```

Then modify the switch case like the following.

```
int numCheckBox = item.numCheckBox;

if(numCheckBox == 1) {
    cb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if(numCheckBox == 2) {
    cb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
} else if(numCheckBox == 3) {
    cb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    cb3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Once the items are populated correctly, you can receive the actions on those checkbox items accordingly.

I hope you get the idea. Please let me know if there is anything else I can help you with.

Edit:

You do not have to loop through the checkboxes as you can explicitly set the `onCheckedChangeListener` to each of your checkbox which will save your desired values in SQLite. The invisible checkbox will not have any effect on their listener. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try your solution as soon as possible :)

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can cicle through those checkboxes in order to get the state of the checkboxes? Because I want to save the state of the checkboxes with SQLite, but I’m not sure how I can get the state of each checkbox

Comment: Please check the updated answer. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Where do I have to set the onCheckedChangeListener? In my getView() method?

Comment: Yes, you might set that in your `getView` method. Glad to know that it helped! Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Another question :D If the left checkbox in a row with multiple checkboxes gets checked, all checkboxes on the right side should also get checked. How can I achieve that? My plan was setting an onCheckedChangeListener for each checkbox. If cb3 gets checked, cb2 and cb1 are set checked from the inner class of onCheckedChangeListener. But I always get "Variable is accessed within inner class. Needs to be declared final." Any ideas? Should I start a new topic for this question?

Comment: I think you should write another question with the current code that you have right now. Please provide me with the link here so that I can take a look as well. Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52596746/android-checking-one-checkbox-checks-all-checkboxes-in-the-same-row